# Storing Table row data in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a sample project named **Visa Consulting Software** using the HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and JavaScript. In this project i have created a sidebar which contains various fields like **Appointment**. On clicking the appointment in sidebar a dynamic table appears which contains data from online API.

**Problem**:- I need to open a new page on clicking of particular table row which contains data of that particular row in form.

**Appointment.html**

```
<div class="table" id="formfetch" style="margin-left: -7%;margin-top: 1%;" >
<table class="table table-hover" style="overflow: hidden;width: 70%;"  id="displaytable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">ID</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">First Name</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Last Name</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Email</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Address</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Contact</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Visa Type</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Country</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Date</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Time</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Appoint. Status</th
<th style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black;">Preview</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody  id="demo" style="padding-left: 10px;border-collapse: collaps;color: blue;position: relative;border: 2px solid black;"></tbody>  
</table>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
function new_page()
 {
    window.open("file:///C:/Users/DITSDev7/Desktop/Visa%20Consultancy/new.html");
     var mySS=[];
     var newTable= document.getElementById("displaytable");
     var rowLength=newTable.rows;
     for (var i=0; i<rowLength;i++)
     {
      var newCell = newTable.rows.item(i).cells;
      for(var j=0; j<newCell;j++)
     {
      console.log(mySS.push(newCell));
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should add some table rows to your example (not only header). Adding the form will also be good.

Comment: Anton: Please elaborate

Comment: I do not understand this answer. I just asked for some HTML, because I see table only on the picture... Oh! By the way, I hope this is not the real phones and emails of people, otherwise you should remove this image :)

Comment: Anton: Yes, this is not real phone and emails

Comment: And again. You problem is more complex than I see code examples here. For example, when do function `new_page()` called? Why it is iterating all the table if you need only 1 row?

Comment: Anton: That's what i need to know that why whole length of the table is getting iterated rather then the values of single row in a table

Comment: When do function new_page() called?

Comment: Anton: When we click on preview button that is in the table

Comment: Will you give us HTML code of some of your rows?